# Father-like or fatherly

Tags: vocabulary

A man who is fatherly or brotherly towards a female, wouldn't like clubbing with her.

What does the sentence 'A man who is fatherly or brotherly towards a female' sound like to you as an English user?

It is about someone who is not our real father or brother but we respect and care for that person as our father or brother.

Comment: I've been clubbing with my sister. Not sure why I might not?

Comment: My question is not about clubbing. People do what they want. Actually, I am asking about the phrase 'fatherly towards a female' what does this sound like?

Comment: Your title is about "sisterly" but the body of the question is about "fatherly".  Can you edit to make this consistent.

Comment: @James K The change recommended has been made.

Comment: It's more about his behaviour towards her than her feelings about him. He cares about her and is concerned for her safety without being romantically interested in her.

Answer (score 1):

'Fatherly' describes a relationship that is father-like. So, logically, anything that one might expect a father to feel about a situation, someone with a fatherly relationship might also feel the same.

The point about clubbing is opinion-based, but I appreciate that is just an example and not the point of the question. But, if it has been established in the writing that a father would not approve of clubbing, or that exists in your culture or the culture being written about, then it seems reasonable that this stance could be explained by the 'fatherly' relationship.

Answer (score 1):

"Fatherly" or "Brotherly" suggests protective and affectionate.  With "Fatherly" also suggesting a significant age difference.

"Female" is odd, we'd normally use "woman" for a female human. As a noun, "female" is mostly for animals.